# Differential Equation $\frac{dP}{dt} = kP(1-P)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about solving this differential equation.

So, the question is to solve it given that $P(0)=\frac23$

So this is what I've done so far

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = kP(1-P)$$
$$ k\,dt = \frac{dP}{P(1-P)}$$
$$ \int{k\,dt} = \int\frac{dP}{P(1-P)} $$
$$ kt + C = \ln(P) - \ln(1-P) $$
$$ \frac23k + C = \ln(0) - \ln(1) $$

This is where I'm lost in finding $C$ because $\ln(0)$ is $-\infty$ Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Semiclassical Oh, yeah. Forgot about that! My main point was that the integral of the product is not necessarily the product of the integrals.

Comment: @alexqwx He didn't multiply them; he used partial fractions then integrated.

Comment: @oliveeuler The reason I'm sceptical about that is that he wrote it as $\ln(P)-\ln(1-P)$ rather than $\ln(P)-\ln(P-1)$ (not that it matters, since we're dealing with absolute values as Semiclassical pointed out).

Comment: @alexqwx: Plus we both looked for some formal mistake when it was just an arithmetic slip.

Comment: @alexqwx Very true. I find it quite irksome when people omit the absolute values :)

Comment: No absolute values are necessary when $0<P<1$, which appears to be intended as I suspect it's a kind of real world application.

Comment: @IlikeSerena He posted the question about an hour ago & it was about population. So really, $P\in\mathbb{N}$ (I'd be interested to see a population study with $0<P<1$).

Comment: @oliveeuler: Now I'm confused. I'm interpreting P as some kind of proportion. It seems to me it has to be if $P(0)=\frac 23$. But maybe I did not see the original question.

Comment: @IlikeSerena $P(t)$ was originally population as a function of time but he got his variables the wrong way round (it was supposed to be $P(\frac{2}{3})=0$). Here's the original question http://bit.ly/WM7HwT . I didn't report this one as a duplicate because there were no answers on the previous one.

Comment: @olive euler no, the question states that P(0) = 2/3

Comment: @oliveeuler: Ah, I see what you mean. Still, the differential equation makes no sense if P is a population number. As a proportion however, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @IlikeSerena Sorry about that, Panthy's right; he originally wrote it as $P(0)=\frac{2}{3}$ with $P$ as population in $10\,000$'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right on track except for the last step.

When filling in $P(0)=\frac23$, you should fill in $t=0$ and $P=\frac 23$.
So:
$$kt+C=\ln P - \ln(1-P)$$
$$k\cdot 0+C=\ln \frac23 - \ln(1-\frac23)$$
$$C=\ln 2$$

Comment: Ah thank you, silly mistake on my part!

Answer (score 2):

You set $P=0$ and $t=2/3$.

But you needed $t=0$ and $P=2/3$.

Answer (score 2):

You found

$$kt+C=\ln(P(t))-\ln(1-P(t))$$
so for $t=0$ and since $P(0)=\frac23$ we have 
$$C=\ln\left(\frac{\frac23}{1-\frac23}\right)=\ln2$$
Now we express $P$ as function of $t$ so
$$\frac{P(t)}{1-P(t)}=2e^{kt}\iff P(t)=2e^{kt}-2P(t)e^{kt}\iff P(t)=\frac{2e^{kt}}{1+2e^{kt}}$$

Comment: I have a tiny question: If P(1) = 8/10 what is k?
When i substitute the values in I get some random answer on wolfram alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8%2F10+%3D+%282e%5Ek%29%2F%281%2B2e%5Ek%29+solve+for+k

Comment: Just we need to solve for $k$ the equation
$$\frac8{10}=\frac25 e^k\iff k=\ln 2$$